# javascript issue in Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, java, oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am pretty new to this ADF, 
I have used fusion charts dragnode in my application,
its from the below website:
http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/java/introduction.html

in my jsff page the code used is given in comment,

The code is working fine on local run but not running on server. any ideas as to why this is happening? the .js is getting created correctly on server but not displayed on page.

Comment: <af:resource type="javascript" source="/JavaScript/jquery-1.7.1.js"/>
<af:resource source="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="javascript"/>
<af:resource type="javascript" source="/JavaScript/jquery-ui.js"/>
<af:resource source="/FusionCharts/js/fusioncharts.js" type="javascript"/>
<af:resource type="javascript" source="/FusionCharts/js/fusioncharts.powercharts.js"/>
<af:resource source="/JavaScript/jquery.bpopup.min.js" type="javascript"/>
<af:resource type="javascript" source="path on server/path on local">

Comment: Check your path and file case. If you tested it on windows it may ignore case. However on server side it may be case sensitive.

Comment: I did cd into the path from backend it is successful.. when the page is displayed i checked the inspector the resources tags are absent in the head section of the generated html. in the address bar if i got to faces/resource/js/filesname.js its there

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are not using the built-in charts that ADF provides?
Probably will eliminate these type of integration issues.
Some samples:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/chart/gallery.jspx